# Creating graph with x-axis only using D3

Tags: d3.js, charts, highcharts, c3, xcharts

I want to look for tutorials for creating a graph like the one below, but i don't seem to know the name of such a graph. [image: Image example]

Can any one tell me the name of such a graph, or point me to tutorials i can check out.

Answer (score 1):

The kind of chart you have illustrated is more commonly referred to as a 'gauge', it shows progress towards some form of goal.

(as an aside, an axis in D3 is a visual rendering of a scale - so what you would want in this case is a scale, not an axis!)

Using D3 for this would be overkill. A simple ratio calculation will give you the 'size' of the filled section. You can then render this gauge as simple HTML with CSS to give you your rounded corners / fill.

Comment: thank you. Is it all possible to show me an example on a fiddle of the code i can write for something like that using the simple technique of css and html?